# Why does my left join query produce more rows than the number of rows in the left table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I am doing some task with PLSQL. It is good for several task I am doing but in this case, I don't know what happened with my join Query.

I have these query:

```
    WITH
        subsi AS (
            SELECT
                mrk2.CUSTOMER_NUMBER ,
                mrk2.CUSTOMER_NAME ,
                mrk2.GROUP_NAME 
            FROM MOJU_REV_KLASIFIKASI mrk2
            WHERE mrk2.GROUP_NAME LIKE '%' || 'Anak perusahaan' || '%'
                OR mrk2.GROUP_NAME LIKE '%' || 'Anak Perusahaan dari Entitas Asosiasi Telkom Group' || '%'
                OR mrk2.GROUP_NAME LIKE '%' || 'Anak Perusahaan' || '%'
        ),
        agentColRef1 AS (
            SELECT 
                mrka.CONTRACT_NUMBER ,
                mrka.BP_NUMBER ,
                mrka.CUSTOMER_NAME ,
                mrka.GROUP_NAME ,
                mrka.UBIS ,
                mrka.REFR ,
                mrka.GL_ACC ,
                mrka.TOT_COST ,
                mak.KL_REF1 AS NAMA_MITRA,
                mak.KL_REF2 AS KL_NUMBER    
            FROM
                MOJU_REV_KK43_ADJ mrka
            LEFT JOIN MOJU_AGENT_KK11 mak ON mrka.CONTRACT_NUMBER = mak.CONTRACT_NUMBER 
            WHERE mrka.tahun = 2022 AND mrka.q = 6 AND mrka.TOT_COST != 0 AND mrka.REFR = '1.1'
            GROUP BY mrka.CONTRACT_NUMBER , mrka.BP_NUMBER , mrka.CUSTOMER_NAME, mrka.GROUP_NAME , mrka.ubis, mrka.refr,
            mrka.GL_ACC , mrka.TOT_COST, mak.KL_REF1 , mak.KL_REF2 
        ),
        agentColRef2 AS (
            SELECT 
                mrka.CONTRACT_NUMBER ,
                mrka.BP_NUMBER ,
                mrka.CUSTOMER_NAME ,
                mrka.GROUP_NAME ,
                mrka.UBIS ,
                mrka.REFR ,
                mrka.GL_ACC ,
                mrka.TOT_COST ,
                mak.KL_REF1 AS NAMA_MITRA,
                mak.KL_REF2 AS KL_NUMBER    
            FROM
                MOJU_REV_KK43_ADJ mrka
            LEFT JOIN MOJU_AGENT_KK12 mak ON mrka.CONTRACT_NUMBER = mak.CONTRACT_NUMBER 
            WHERE mrka.tahun = 2022 AND mrka.q = 6 AND mrka.TOT_COST != 0 AND mrka.REFR = '1.2'
            GROUP BY mrka.CONTRACT_NUMBER , mrka.BP_NUMBER , mrka.CUSTOMER_NAME, mrka.GROUP_NAME , mrka.ubis, mrka.refr,
            mrka.GL_ACC , mrka.TOT_COST, mak.KL_REF1 , mak.KL_REF2 
        ),
        agentColRef3 AS (
            SELECT 
                mrka.CONTRACT_NUMBER ,
                mrka.BP_NUMBER ,
                mrka.CUSTOMER_NAME ,
                mrka.GROUP_NAME ,
                mrka.UBIS ,
                mrka.REFR ,
                mrka.GL_ACC ,
                mrka.TOT_COST ,
                mak.KL_REF1 AS NAMA_MITRA,
                mak.KL_REF2 AS KL_NUMBER    
            FROM
                MOJU_REV_KK43_ADJ mrka
            LEFT JOIN MOJU_AGENT_KK13 mak ON mrka.CONTRACT_NUMBER = mak.CONTRACT_NUMBER 
            WHERE mrka.tahun = 2022 AND mrka.q = 6 AND mrka.TOT_COST != 0 AND mrka.REFR = '1.3'
            GROUP BY mrka.CONTRACT_NUMBER , mrka.BP_NUMBER , mrka.CUSTOMER_NAME, mrka.GROUP_NAME , mrka.ubis, mrka.refr,
            mrka.GL_ACC , mrka.TOT_COST, mak.KL_REF1 , mak.KL_REF2 
        ),
        agentColRefUnion AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM agentColRef1
            UNION
            SELECT *
            FROM agentColRef2
            UNION
            SELECT *
            FROM agentColRef3
        ),
        agentColAlok1 AS ( 
            SELECT 
                ac.CONTRACT_NUMBER AS CONTRACT_NUMBER ,
                ac.BP_NUMBER AS BP_NUMBER ,
                ac.CUSTOMER_NAME AS CUSTOMER_NAME ,
                ac.GROUP_NAME AS GROUP_NAME ,
                ac.ubis,
                ac.REFR ,
                ac.GL_ACC ,
                ac.TOT_COST ,
                ac.NAMA_MITRA,
                ac.KL_NUMBER,
                mabc.GL AS AKUN_BEBAN_1
            FROM 
                agentColRefUnion ac
            LEFT OUTER JOIN MOJU_AGENT_BEBAN_CPE mabc ON ac.KL_NUMBER = mabc.KL
            GROUP BY ac.CONTRACT_NUMBER , ac.BP_NUMBER , ac.CUSTOMER_NAME, ac.GROUP_NAME , ac.ubis, ac.refr,
            ac.GL_ACC , ac.TOT_COST, ac.nama_mitra , ac.kl_number, mabc.GL
        ),
        agentColAlok2 AS ( 
            SELECT 
                ac.CONTRACT_NUMBER,
                ac.BP_NUMBER ,
                ac.CUSTOMER_NAME ,
                ac.GROUP_NAME ,
                ac.ubis,
                ac.REFR ,
                ac.GL_ACC ,
                ac.TOT_COST ,
                ac.NAMA_MITRA,
                ac.KL_NUMBER,
                ac.AKUN_BEBAN_1,
                CASE
                    WHEN (ac.AKUN_BEBAN_1 IS NULL) THEN maba.BEBAN_DNAPSO ELSE to_char(ac.AKUN_BEBAN_1)
                END AS AKUN_BEBAN_2
            FROM 
                agentColAlok1 ac
            LEFT JOIN MOJU_AGENT_BEBAN_AKUN maba ON ac.GL_ACC = maba.GL_REVENUE 
        ),
        agentColTp AS (
            SELECT 
                ac.CONTRACT_NUMBER,
                ac.BP_NUMBER ,
                ac.CUSTOMER_NAME ,
                ac.GROUP_NAME ,
                ac.ubis,
                ac.REFR ,
                ac.GL_ACC ,
                ac.TOT_COST ,
                ac.NAMA_MITRA,
                ac.KL_NUMBER,
                ac.AKUN_BEBAN_1,
                ac.AKUN_BEBAN_2,
                mrl.CUSTOMER_TP 
            FROM 
                agentColAlok2 ac
            LEFT JOIN MOJU_REV_LTP mrl ON ac.NAMA_MITRA = mrl.SUBSIDIARIES 
        )

    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM agentColAlok2 aca
    WHERE aca.nama_mitra IS NOT NULL AND aca.nama_mitra != 'N/A'
```

When I run my `agenColAlok2` to get the counts, it appears to have 911 records, but when I run my  `agentColTp` I got 11090 records. Because it execute the results from `agentColAlok2` I expect it should have 911 records also.

I have tried with INNER JOIN instead but still the records is different from what I expected. Also, the results from `agentColAlok1` and `agentColAlok2` is also not same. I have 833 records on `agentColAlok1` and 911 records on `agentColAlok2`

Why it can be like that? Am I missing some concept about join or with clause? Any of you have an answer or have experienced same issue? Thank you.

The Joined table should get same exact records result

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example should help to explain it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8d8e5/1

In the example, I create two tables, `a` and `b`, and insert some data into them.

`a`:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |

`b`:

| Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 3 | 10 |

Then I run the query:

`select * from a left join b on a.col1=b.col3`

Which returns:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 9 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 10 |

Note there are multiple matches for `a.col1` in `b.col3`, so the count of the result was determined by the size of `b` rather than `a`.

Comment: Ah ok so if there was multiple match on the right column, it will also recorded as multiple results in the resulted table. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The final query is missing the `JOIN` keyword and `ON` clause for the `subsi` and `agentColRef` tables. It should look something like this:

```
SELECT
    subsi.CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
    subsi.CUSTOMER_NAME,
    ...
    ...
FROM subsi
JOIN agentColRef1 ON subsi.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = agentColRef1.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
JOIN agentColRef2 ON subsi.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = agentColRef2.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
JOIN agentColRef3 ON subsi.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = agentColRef3.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```